# Yet another genie and three wishes short story

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Yes, yet another genie and three wishes story, a short-short. In this one, the genie starts out by saying "Here are the rules—" and the person who has the wishes interrupts, "First wish: no rules."

Can anybody place it? I'm sure I read this one recently, but can't put my finger on where.

Comment: Isn't it the start of a joke?

Comment: You might mean the fourth wish in https://xkcd.com/1086/